# Как нажать на кнопку selenium

Tags: python, selenium

У меня есть код на selenium и мне надо нажать на кнопку. Я легко нажимаю на формы по типу логин, но на кнопки нажимать не доводилось. Вот развёртка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все так же как и на формах.

```
btn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]')
btn.click()
```

То есть, ищите кнопку по XPATH и кликаете на неё.
Вам нужно скопировать XPATH, если у вас на картинке, то вот по этому тэгу: <button class="component-button has-icon"...